# Django South cloned project

Tags: django, django-south

I have just started using South (finally) and it is really a great tool. I started a project and did a few initial migrations to get the feel of South. I have now just git cloned this project onto a new machine. In do not have the database data, as there was no data enter yet.

My question is what are the steps to rebuild the database?

I have tried:

```
 ./manage.py schemamigration <myapp> --auto
```

and:

```
 ./manage.py migrate <myapp>
```

But it says nothing seems to have changed.

Do I also need to run an initial syncdb? Will the South migration history be intact?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote here? I assumed this to be a valid question for someone new to South.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to run syncdb initially to load the south migration history table

> Edit your settings.py and put ‘south’ into INSTALLED_APPS (assuming you’ve installed it to the right place)
>
> Run ./manage.py syncdb to load the South table into the database. Note that syncdb looks different now - South modifies it.
>
> Run ./manage.py convert_to_south myapp - South will automatically make and pretend to apply your first migration.

See [Converting an App](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app)